# How to hide / show secondary nav using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I have two levels of navigation on my site. The navigation hides / shows certain  sections of the 1 page site when selected. What I'm trying to do is have the secondary navigation hidden while the `#selected-work` navigation link is in-active. Once the `#selected-work` like is selected I would like my secondary navigation to be shown. So far I have some jquery set up to run the `hashchange`function & hide / show the different content areas, but I'm at a loss of how to accomplish my goal with the secondary navigation. All suggestions are very welcome.

Here's my code for those secitons:

HTML

```
<div id="header-nav-float-wrap">

<!--main navigation-->
<ul class="nav-list">
    <li><a href="#selected-work" id="selected-work-link">Selected Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#cv">CV</a></li>                           
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>


 <!-- Secondary Nav -->

 <div id="left-nav-wrapper">
    <div id="left-nav">
   <ul class="left-nav-list">
    <li><a href="#painting">Painting</a></li>
    <li><a href="#drawing">Drawing</a></li>
        <li><a href="#design">Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#commissions">Commissions</a></li>
   </ul>
    </div>

 </div>



  <div id="main-content-wrapper">
<div id="main-content">
       <!-- default page content -->
   <div id="default" class="content-pages">
       <img src="img/painting1.jpg">
   </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$(window).on("hashchange", function(e) {
    $(location.hash.length > 1 ? location.hash : "#default").siblings().hide().end().show();
}).trigger("hashchange");


});
```

Comment: Your question seems incomplete and not fully elaborated. What about the other links in main-navigation? what about other contents... I'm a bit lost

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your html I can't be certain but could you not add the secondary navigation to your `#selected-work` element and use some absolute positioning to get it in the right place. Then it would only be shown when the `#selected-work` is shown.  I would also suggesting using the `:target` pseudo class to show and hide the active sections instead of the javascsript.

Comment: Response part 1: I apologize if my question was a bit vague. @roXon The other links in the main navigation change up the content that is displayed in the `#main-content` section of the site. As each nav link is selected (ie. #selected-work, #cv, #contact) the `#main-content` area shows / hides each corresponding div. The "selected work section of the site will have two layers of displayed content. When the main nav link for #selected-work is click (from `#nav-list`) the a page is displayed within the `#main-content` section of the site. (see part 2)

Comment: Response part 2: (continue from part 1) .... At this point I would like the `.left-nav-list` to appear. When any other `#nav-list` link is selected (ie. #cv, #contact) I would like the `.left-nav-list` to disappear. Does that make sense?

Comment: WHat I don't understant is you have an `#default` page. How you get back to that page after you open some other page?

Comment: @Jrod Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fqkyz/) that I've loaded a majority of what I have so far into. There's a bunch of missing images (since they're hosted locally) and a couple `alert()` functions simply for testing. For the most part you can get a feel for what I'm trying to do with the navigation. The nav down the left side (`.left-nav-list`) should only be shown when the selected work's nav link is selected. Make sense?

Comment: @roXon I have a logo in the top lefthand corner that act's as an anchor to the #default content. Simply it links to the root url using href="#"

Comment: it would be so nice you take a look at my answer... and leave a comment

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/aloqis/2)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {


  $(window).on("hashchange", function(e) {

    var hashID = window.location.hash;

    $(hashID.length > 1 ? hashID : "#default").show().siblings().hide();

    var show_hide = hashID=='#selected-work' ? 'show' : 'hide';
    $('#left-nav-wrapper')[show_hide]();

  }).trigger("hashchange");



});
```

Comment: hmm...it's hiding the entire `#left-nav-wrapper` div. I was hoping the div would stay since it's part of the page's design. I just want the links hidden until `selected-work` link is clicked. Then the entire left nav will appear and when any of the links are click in the left nav the appropriate content will show up in the main content area of the page. Also when any of those left nav links are click the other nav links should not disappear....